# What's the difference between Camera.apk and com.sec.android.app.camera.apk?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, camera, system

I'm trying to install a [modified version](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=949566) of the Camera app on my rooted Samsung Galaxy S (Captivate) through copying to `/system/app` and through installing a zip file via ClockWorkRecovery.  It doesn't seem to be working (based on the fact that the modified camera should have no geotagging).

Looking in my /system/app/ folder I have `Camera.apk` and `com.sec.android.app.camera.apk`.  Are these complementary files or are they different camera app files?  `Camera.apk` has a timestamp of August 1, 2008 (which doesn't seem right) and the other has a timestamp of August 1, 2011 (which is around the time I was playing around with this stuff).

Comment: Are you running a deodexed ROM?  That's required for replacing system apps.

Comment: @Matthew, I believe so.  It's Serendipity, and this link (http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/get-serendipity-custom-rom-for-samsung-captivate/) says it is.  Although I'm not sure what that means exactly.  I was able to push an mms.apk app successfully in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Serendipity ROM only contains Camera.apk and CameraFirmware.apk.  I would think that the version you're trying to copy over is being renamed by the system on reboot and the original Camera.apk is being restored.

What I would try:

1. Get the non-CWM version of the Camera.apk and put it on your SD card
2. On your phone, use Root Explorer or similar to mount `/system/app/` as RW
3. Rename `/system/app/Camera.apk` to Camera.bak or something
4. Copy in the new apk from the SD card
5. Remount `/system/app/` as RO, you may want to make sure `/system/` is RO as well
6. Try to use the camera.  If it works, reboot and see if it still works.

Comment: That works, thanks.  Well, it works in that I'm running the new Camera version.  It's just that this Camera mod does not disable geotagging as the website claims.

Comment: @Chance I haven't read the whole thread but I saw this: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=11273491&postcount=3

Comment: I saw that, perhaps I can't find the menu they are talking about.